# after using 'udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdb', is there any way to use '/dev/sdb' again without physically reconnecting usb flash drive?

Tags: usb, drive

Rarely my flash drive doesnt work properly and it needs to be reconnected. Instead of manually reconnecting it, I'm powering it off using 'udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdb'. Is there any way to "power it on" again without the need to physically disconnect my flash drive?